# Angular 2 corrupt s3 image with signed url

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload an image on s3 based on a signed url that my backend gives me. In postman everything work as expected when loading the image as binary, here the javascript translation

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");

var file = "<file contents here>";

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: file,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("my-signed-url", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

In angular otherwise I really can't understand why it's not working. The image seems corrupted once uploaded to s3 bucket.

```
  onUpload() {
    const amzUrl = 'my-signed-url';

    // selected file is from: this.selectedFile = event.target.files;

    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', this.selectedFile[0]);
    this.http.put(amzUrl, fd).subscribe(
      () => {

      }
    );
  }
```